# Error when register database with ArcGIS server, failure to access the DBMS

Tags: arcgis-server, sql-server

The connection property set was missing a required property or the property value was unrecognized. Failure to access the DBMS server:

[image]

```
Machine: DESKTOP-TFF79J4 [db: The connection property set was missing a required property or the property value was unrecognized. Failure to access the DBMS server]
```

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour].  All questions should include as much information about the environment as possible.  In this case, you're missing the version of ArcGIS Server, the RDBMS you are attempting the register, the exact release of the RDBMS, the exact parameters (except password) you have provided, and indication of what steps you have taken to make the RDBMS client library accessible to the Server.

Comment: What database are you trying to connect to? (yes, it makes a lot of difference). Can you explain, in steps, how you're connecting and what properties *are* set (black out any personal info please). Are you able to connect to the database from ArcCatalog (or QGIS depending on the database engine)? Have you been able to connect to your database server from ArcGIS Server previously? (some database engines can have multiple databases - PostGIS for example, some don't - like Oracle).

Comment: I am trying to connect to SQL server (2008). I have successfully connected to the database from ArcCatalog,but when i trying to register database with ArcGis Server the error exist.@MichaelStimson

Comment: the connection might not like that Hyphen in your connection. "Make sure you are escaping the names"   > https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20995394/can-i-give-sql-server-database-name-with-hyphen-like-abc-123

Comment: thanks for answer,The version of ArcGIS Server is 10.2 and database is SQL server 2008R2. The exact parameters:
register database with ArcGis server
name:xxxx
publisher database connection :
SERVER=(instance name);INSTANCE=xxxx;sqlever:(instance name);DBCL...
server database connection 
the same with publisher
SERVER=(instance name);INSTANCE=xxxx;sqlever:(instance name);DBCL...
Then i get the error : The connection property set was missing a required property or the property value was unrecognized. Failure to access the DBMS server @Vince

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but that is not may Question@Mapperz

Comment: Please [Edit] the question to contain these details.  They're far more legible in the question, ArcGIS 10.2 has a month remaining before retirement. Modern releases don't support SQL-Server 2008 at all, just because it's so old.  It sounds like you don't have the proper drivers on the Server host, but it's difficult to tell without more information.